# How do I redirect a page based on the browser user agent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, user-agent

I am using this script to detect the string "safari" in the user agent header which then redirects you to "android.html" how would I change the code to make it so it redirects if the user agent header does NOT contain "safari"?

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("safari") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
window.location = 'android.html';
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is my revised code. Does this make sense? It first detects whether the device is android or not then it redirects if it is a safari browser.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
    var isSafari = ua.indexOf("safari") == -1;
        if(isAndroid) {
        if(isSafari) {
        window.location = 'android.html';
        }
        }
```

Comment: you always has else block right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to go with the name of the variable, change the condition from `> -1` to `== -1`.

```
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("safari") == -1;
if(isAndroid) {
   window.location = 'android.html';
}
```

Comment: +1 for it being easily readable, "if isAndroid, go to android.html"

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!isAndroid) {
window.location = 'android.html';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser specific detection is usually not the preferred approach as it's usually better to use feature detection. Have you thought about modernizr?
http://www.modernizr.com/